# Why the USB serial port or openocd won't open without root permission?

Tags: permissions, usb, serial-port

minicom or openocd command won't run without root permission on a Ubuntu 16.04 system.

In the past, I was able to open serial port without root permission.

I verified that the current user exist in dialout and plugdev groups. Also, I don't know if it matters but since this looks like a USB issue, I have three USB dongles - Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, and Logitech Unifying receiver connected.

Any thoughts on what could be going on?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l` for the device file?

Comment: (All usb device files can be found with <code>find /dev</code>

Comment: First, can you verify that the expected usb modules are loaded? "lsmod | grep usb" is one way to determine this

Comment: Output of `ls -l` for the device file: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun 29 14:40 /dev/serial/by-id/usb-ARM_DAPLink_CMSIS-DAP_044400014bcc019d00000000000000000000000097969906-if01 -> ../../ttyACM0`.
This is the device I'm trying to connect to.

Comment: @llywrch, I don't understand what to look for in the output of `lsmod | grep usb`. Here's the output:
`btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             557056  36 btrtl,hidp,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
usb_storage            69632  2 uas
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  5 hidp,usbhid,hid_generic,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
`

Comment: `ls -l /dev/ttyACM0`. What is the group? `sudo adduser $USER the_,group`, logout and login.

Comment: Thanks, @waltinator. Like I mentioned in the post, the current user is already in the group. It is plugdev group, output of your command.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at all of the info in the comments, Keyur, I'm see some possible problems here.

The biggest issue, & this may be the most important, is that you are running an old version of Ubuntu. You report you are using 16.04; the current version (which has long-term support) is 20.04. Consider upgrading -- that alone may resolve this issue. (And if you ask for help with openocd, one of the standard replies you can expect to receive is "Are you using the latest version of Ubuntu?")

I won't insist on this, though. For strange reasons, developers will refuse to upgrade & remain with old, unsupported operating systems; you may be in this situation. I know of one commercial performance application which, last I heard, still doesn't work with the Linux 5.0 kernel. But if there are no good reasons for you not to be using Ubuntu 20.4, all the more reason to upgrade.

A possible issue is that the USB device identifies itself as "usb-ARM_DAPLink_CMSIS-DAP" suggesting it uses an ARM chip which may be different than your usual usb chip. (I'll admit I'm guessing here, but I see drivers that appear to support blue tooth, & drivers that support logitech -- so wouldn't it be reasonable to assume we'd see one with "arm" in its name?) I also note on their website https://armmbed.github.io/DAPLink/ "DAPLink has superseded the mbed CMSIS-DAP interface firmware project", so there may be an incompatibility in how the application you are using with this USB device -- which appears to be openocd -- was compiled.

If neither of these help with your problem, come back with the results & we'll ponder things some more.